# flex browser application initialization

Tags: apache-flex, adobe

Would anyone be able to point out some good tutorials on creating applications in flex that are don't have UI's?

Actually, it looks like all I really need to know is how to call a function upon initialization of the flash object. I tried the creationComplete attribute, but it doesn't work in browser.

Comment: Why would you want to use Flex for something like this?  The primary reason to use Flex is that it offers a robust UI Framework.

Comment: All i want is a way to connect my javascript app to a java server. I know there are websockets, but 1) the messages are in binary, and 2) there is no api for javascript. But there is API and REALLY good documentation for ActionScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure what made it work finally, but I ended up copying and pasting this code from some website (sorry, i don't remember the site):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- wrapper/CheckExternalInterface.mxml -->
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    creationComplete="initApp()">
</s:Application>
```

And that ended up working! thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you're intent is to connect JavaScript to a Java Server, why not use [XMLHTTPRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)?  IT is the basis of every AJAX style RIA application.  The data format you pass back and forth can either be JSON or XML.  It doesn't have to be binary.

Second, you don't need Flex for this.  The [Sockets](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html) APIs in ActionScript and are part of the Flash Player.  You can use them without any dependencies to the Flex Framework.

Comment: Actually, the server I'm using only uses binary. And yes, I do have to use this web server.

Comment: @LordZardeck What server are you using?  What protocol are you using to send data from your client to the server?